# How do I make 2 overlapping row elements with the same parent have the same height in CSS, where the z-index differs?

Tags: css, layout

I am looking to make the div with the background on the left and right hand side, fill up the height of its container or be the height of another div the container contains (the magenta one).

Below are is an image.

[image: resurrected clean layout problem]

[Here is a JS Fiddle with my working code with a preview.](https://jsfiddle.net/desbest/1u32knyb/16/)

```
<div class="outercontainer">
            
            <div class="innercontainerback orangeborder"></div>

            <div class="innercontainer padding1 magenta">
                    

Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Aliquam convallis id tellus vitae ultrices. Phasellus elit leo, vulputate et malesuada ac, venenatis vel augue. Mauris maximus ex ac orci blandit auctor. Praesent lectus dolor, pretium vitae ultricies vel, accumsan a ante. Fusce blandit semper suscipit. Vivamus ultricies ipsum et finibus malesuada. Aliquam tempor, tellus in bibendum fringilla, nunc lacus posuere sem, nec elementum enim eros a massa. Maecenas eleifend elementum nisi accumsan luctus. Aenean ac tortor mollis, aliquam magna vel, aliquet sapien. Fusce purus quam, pulvinar quis enim nec, ornare luctus felis. Aliquam consectetur dapibus dictum. Morbi et ex eu risus euismod viverra sit amet sit amet augue. Nam mollis hendrerit tincidunt. Sed posuere suscipit ipsum id sagittis. Mauris quis sapien vitae mi tristique accumsan. Praesent cursus dui vehicula leo viverra venenatis.

            </div>

            
            

    </div>
```

And below is my CSS

```
html, body, .outercontainer, .innercontainerback { height: 100%; min-height: 100%; }

body {
    margin: 0px;
    padding: 0px;
    font-family: Tahoma;
}

.outercontainer {
    width: 100%;
}

.innercontainerback, .innercontainer { width: 400px; }

.magenta { background-color: magenta; }
.orangeborder { border: 5px solid orange; }


.innercontainerback {
    /*margin-left: auto; margin-right: auto;*/
    background-image: url('https://i.imgur.com/vvaALIn.png'), url('https://i.imgur.com/trZrIdu.png');
    background-position: left, right;
    background-repeat: repeat-y, repeat-y;
    opacity: 0.88;
    z-index: 1; position: absolute; 
  /* left: 50%;  margin-left: -400px;  */
 top: 0px;
}

.innercontainer {
    /* height: 100%; */
 min-height: 100%; 
/*  margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto; */
    opacity: 1 !important;
    position: relative; z-index: 0;
    clear: both;
}

.padding1 { 
    padding-left: 90px; padding-right: 90px; box-sizing: border-box;
    padding-top: 32px;
    /*margin-top: 32px; */
}
```

How do I make 2 overlapping elements with the same parent have the same height in CSS of which both divs are not columns, and the z-index differs?

Comment: (1) remove height: 100%; from outercontainer (2) add position:relative to outercontainer

Comment: by the way, why not having only one div and apply background to it?

Comment: The reason why I have 2 divs instead of applying a background to one div and putting the content in that same one, is because the web design I am making has a 100% width header and opacity effects are used on that. This header is not in the code sample or js fiddle. CSS does not allow web developers to set the opacity of an element to be below 1 to be translucent, while child elements have an opacity of 1 to be opaque. See this image to see the desired effect. https://imgur.com/a/539zeS7

Comment: Thank you for your comment. My question is now solved. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remove `height: 100%` from outercontainer and add `position:relative` to outercontainer

```css
html,
body,
.innercontainerback {
  height: 100%;
  min-height: 100%;
}

body {
  margin: 0px;
  padding: 0px;
  font-family: Tahoma;
}

.outercontainer {
  min-height: 100%;
  position: relative;
}

.innercontainerback,
.innercontainer {
  width: 400px;
}

.magenta {
  background-color: magenta;
}

.orange {
  background-color: orange;
}

.innercontainerback {
  background-image: url('https://i.imgur.com/vvaALIn.png'), url('https://i.imgur.com/trZrIdu.png');
  background-position: left, right;
  background-repeat: repeat-y, repeat-y;
  opacity: 0.88;
  z-index: 1;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0px;
}

.innercontainer {
  min-height: 100%;
  opacity: 1 !important;
  position: relative;
  z-index: 0;
  clear: both;
}

.padding1 {
  padding-left: 90px;
  padding-right: 90px;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  padding-top: 32px;
}
```

```html
<div class="outercontainer">

  <div class="innercontainerback orange"></div>

  <div class="innercontainer padding1 magenta">


    Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Aliquam convallis id tellus vitae ultrices. Phasellus elit leo, vulputate et malesuada ac, venenatis vel augue. Mauris maximus ex ac orci blandit auctor. Praesent lectus dolor, pretium vitae ultricies
    vel, accumsan a ante. Fusce blandit semper suscipit. Vivamus ultricies ipsum et finibus malesuada. Aliquam tempor, tellus in bibendum fringilla, nunc lacus posuere sem, nec elementum enim eros a massa. Maecenas eleifend elementum nisi accumsan luctus.
    Aenean ac tortor mollis, aliquam magna vel, aliquet sapien. Fusce purus quam, pulvinar quis enim nec, ornare luctus felis. Aliquam consectetur dapibus dictum. Morbi et ex eu risus euismod viverra sit amet sit amet augue. Nam mollis hendrerit tincidunt.
    Sed posuere suscipit ipsum id sagittis. Mauris quis sapien vitae mi tristique accumsan. Praesent cursus dui vehicula leo viverra venenatis. Donec gravida lorem in quam lobortis iaculis. Mauris in feugiat turpis, ut mollis odio. Duis tincidunt massa
    malesuada, suscipit orci et, laoreet odio. In ultrices vel metus eget varius. Vivamus quis libero eu lacus mattis varius. Vestibulum venenatis nisl at ligula gravida iaculis. Vestibulum metus diam, laoreet non mi et, euismod tempor dui. Integer eu
    sapien ut lectus sodales cursus. In nisi nunc, faucibus feugiat velit non, molestie faucibus odio. Curabitur pretium accumsan turpis consectetur gravida. Suspendisse viverra enim a est egestas, vel lobortis augue cursus. Vivamus dignissim porta varius.
    Mauris gravida id augue eget convallis. Nam id dui nec arcu dapibus congue. Sed imperdiet facilisis elementum. Nam sed magna in massa finibus viverra ac vel tortor. Morbi iaculis sollicitudin dolor vulputate luctus. Donec efficitur arcu at mauris
    euismod, sit amet fermentum enim elementum. Praesent sapien sem, fringilla quis elementum a, auctor nec elit. Nunc sed justo non diam efficitur elementum. Aliquam sit amet turpis augue. Quisque ullamcorper nunc in facilisis lacinia. Mauris molestie
    nibh ipsum, vitae malesuada neque blandit pharetra. Nunc viverra convallis odio pretium dictum. Sed imperdiet massa ac libero scelerisque, eget rutrum lorem accumsan. In ac lobortis nibh. Ut id risus id ante aliquet dictum lobortis eu velit. Curabitur
    vitae risus bibendum, condimentum purus et, porta lectus. Nullam non nulla quis urna tincidunt auctor sed a leo.
  </div>




</div>
```

Or simplify your code with a pseudo element and the use if `vh` unit to avoid all the cascading `height`/`min-height`

```css
body {
  margin: 0px;
  padding: 0px;
  font-family: Tahoma;
}

.outercontainer {
  min-height: 100vh;
  display:flex;
  width: 400px;
}

.magenta {
  background-color: magenta;
}

.innercontainer::before {
  content:"";
  background-image: url('https://i.imgur.com/vvaALIn.png'), url('https://i.imgur.com/trZrIdu.png');
  background-position: left, right;
  background-repeat: repeat-y;
  background-color: orange;
  opacity: 0.88;
  z-index: 1;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left:0;
  right:0;
  bottom:0;
}

.innercontainer {
  position: relative;
}

.padding1 {
  padding-left: 90px;
  padding-right: 90px;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  padding-top: 32px;
}
```

```html
<div class="outercontainer">

  <div class="innercontainer padding1 magenta">


    Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Aliquam convallis id tellus vitae ultrices. Phasellus elit leo, vulputate et malesuada ac, venenatis vel augue. Mauris maximus ex ac orci blandit auctor. Praesent lectus dolor, pretium vitae ultricies
    vel, accumsan a ante. Fusce blandit semper suscipit. Vivamus ultricies ipsum et finibus malesuada. Aliquam tempor, tellus in bibendum fringilla, nunc lacus posuere sem, nec elementum enim eros a massa. Maecenas eleifend elementum nisi accumsan luctus.
    Aenean ac tortor mollis, aliquam magna vel, aliquet sapien. Fusce purus quam, pulvinar quis enim nec, ornare luctus felis. Aliquam consectetur dapibus dictum. Morbi et ex eu risus euismod viverra sit amet sit amet augue. Nam mollis hendrerit tincidunt.
    Sed posuere suscipit ipsum id sagittis. Mauris quis sapien vitae mi tristique accumsan. Praesent cursus dui vehicula leo viverra venenatis. Donec gravida lorem in quam lobortis iaculis. Mauris in feugiat turpis, ut mollis odio. Duis tincidunt massa
    malesuada, suscipit orci et, laoreet odio. In ultrices vel metus eget varius. Vivamus quis libero eu lacus mattis varius. Vestibulum venenatis nisl at ligula gravida iaculis. Vestibulum metus diam, laoreet non mi et, euismod tempor dui. Integer eu
    sapien ut lectus sodales cursus. In nisi nunc, faucibus feugiat velit non, molestie faucibus odio. Curabitur pretium accumsan turpis consectetur gravida. Suspendisse viverra enim a est egestas, vel lobortis augue cursus. Vivamus dignissim porta varius.
    Mauris gravida id augue eget convallis. Nam id dui nec arcu dapibus congue. Sed imperdiet facilisis elementum. Nam sed magna in massa finibus viverra ac vel tortor. Morbi iaculis sollicitudin dolor vulputate luctus. Donec efficitur arcu at mauris
    euismod, sit amet fermentum enim elementum. Praesent sapien sem, fringilla quis elementum a, auctor nec elit. Nunc sed justo non diam efficitur elementum. Aliquam sit amet turpis augue. Quisque ullamcorper nunc in facilisis lacinia. Mauris molestie
    nibh ipsum, vitae malesuada neque blandit pharetra. Nunc viverra convallis odio pretium dictum. Sed imperdiet massa ac libero scelerisque, eget rutrum lorem accumsan. In ac lobortis nibh. Ut id risus id ante aliquet dictum lobortis eu velit. Curabitur
    vitae risus bibendum, condimentum purus et, porta lectus. Nullam non nulla quis urna tincidunt auctor sed a leo.
  </div>




</div>
```

Comment: I prefer the first solution. For this question I provided a simplified version of my layout. The version on my computer has more things in it. And the first solution works better for the theme I'm currently working on. Also I've had problems with `vh` before and I don't know what a flexbox is. I don't feel the need to learn flexbox if I'm not going to use it.

Comment: A `100vh` height element does not become larger when its contents overflow off the screen. So if a person has to scroll down to see the rest of the content, the `100vh` element will not expand its size to adapt to the extra content the scrollbar is for. `100%` does.

Comment: @desbest I used min-height not height